# Add Attachments tool failing for some features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attachments, photos

In ArcMap 10.5, I have a feature class in a personal geodatabase, with Attachments Enabled. I have made a match table linking the feature class to the folder where are the photos are stored that I want to attach. This step works well.

When I run the Add Attachments tool, it runs until completed, and some attachments work like expected, but many of the attachments fail with the message:
"Cannot add file 'C:\Users\SJC GIS\Desktop\Photos\482917100019_2016_7.jpg' to feature with OID = 28"

I am unable to notice a difference in photos that do and do not attach. Perhaps file size? The photos range is size from 1 to 6 MB. I don't know the maximum attachment file size ArcMap supports.

Some of the features have multiple photos each, some only have one. There does not appear to be a pattern to when they attach and when they fail. For example, a feature might correctly get 3 of 4 photos attached to it, while another feature gets 0 of 4 attached to it, while another gets 4 of 4 attached to it. They all follow a similar naming convention.

The feature class I want to add attachments to and the match table are in the same geodatabase, the photos are on my desktop. I don't think this is an issue since many of the photos do attach correctly.

This question is similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164948/cannot-load-attachments-with-add-attachment-tool-using-generate-attachment-match?rq=1

Any suggestions why some photos won't attach and some will?

Comment: It is a personal geodatabase, is this an issue?

Comment: I think that could be an important detail for you to [edit] into your question.